# Array of pointers to struct [C++]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

**SPOILER - CODE GIVEN DOWN BELOW IS NOT MINE, BUT MINE TEACHER! THE MAIN TASK IS TO IMPLEMENT NEEDED FUNCTION USING THIS PROJECT AS IS!**

Recently i had an interesting project in my school. We had example program where we needed to implement some required functions.
Basically program works with array of pointer to struct (as i understanded)

Here is sturct:

```
typedef struct Trip {
    int number;
    Date date;
    char *name;
    char *destination;
    int kapacity;
} TRIP;
```

Well basically all functions are using pointers, which i don't completly understand.

```
TRIP* newTrip(const char *nam, const char *des, int kap, Date& dat);
char *getInfo(TRIP* z);
void printInfo(TRIP* z);
```

Realzitation for adding trips and printing info

```
TRIP* newTrip(const char *n, const char *de, int ka, Date& dat) {
    TRIP*z = new TRIP;
    z->number= ++numberOfTrips;
    z->date = dat;
    z->name= new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy_s(z->nazev, strlen(n)+1, n);
    z->destination = new char[strlen(de) + 1];
    strcpy_s(z->destination, strlen(de)+1, de);
    z->kapacity = k;
    return 0;
};

char *getInfo(TRIP *z) {
    char *res;
    char pom[100];
    if (z != NULL) {
        snprintf(pom, 10, "%d %s %s", z->number, z->name, z->destination);
        res = new char[strlen(pom) + 1];
        strcpy_s(res, strlen(pom), pom);
        return res;
    }
    else return NULL;
};

void printTrip(TRIP *z) {
    if (z != NULL) printf("%s\n", getInfo(z);
};
```

So in main we make an pointer array??

```
TRIP* Trips[20];
```

And test adding of trip  (it's not mine)

```
void Test()
{
Trips[numberOfTrips++] = newTrip("Japan", "Tokio", 30, Date(1, 6, 2018));
}
```

Well the first task is to simply add function to print all the trips.
Problem is, when i debug it, struct Trips have zeros in it, after adding some trips.
How to assign it to actual struct and how to print info? 
I tried a lot of methods on internet but nothing works for me.

Simply

```
int main() 
{
...
Test();
for(int i=0; i <= numberofTrips i++)
printInfo(Trips[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Don't work, cause Trips is pointer array?
I need help, it's not for school, it's for me to understand this kind of stuff. Second task is adding Trip from manual input, but thats for later. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to `typedef` your `struct` in c++ to make them type names.

Comment: You could solve all of your problems by using `std::string` to represent your strings and using value semantics.

Comment: Your code make repeated use of some mystery variable `n`, but there is no `n` declared. Ex: `new char[strlen(n) + 1]`. Post *real* code.

Comment: apart from the use of `new` this really isn't C++

Comment: The function `newTrip` ends with `return 0;`, so not too surprising that the array contains zeros. Perhaps you meant to have `return z;`?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by *"Don't work"*. This is too broad and could mean any number of things. Does it not compile? Does it give an unexpected result? Does it crash?

Comment: 1) It's not my code, i need to complete 1 task, printing the info
2) I can't much edit given code, i must work with it as is

Comment: Tell your teacher that C is a different language to C++, and confusing the two leads to programs that are wrong in *both*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the pointer to the created trip and not 0

```
TRIP* newTrip(const char *nam, const char *de, int ka, Date& dat) {
    TRIP*z = new TRIP;
    z->number= ++numberOfTrips;
    z->date = dat;
    z->name= new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy_s(z->nazev, strlen(n)+1, n);
    z->destination = new char[strlen(de) + 1];
    strcpy_s(z->destination, strlen(de)+1, de);
    z->kapacity = k;
    return z;
}
```

btw.: The semicolon at the end of the function after the closing bracket is not necessary. It is only needed with structs and classes (c++)

Comment: Well it's not my code, but teacher's. I just trying to complete the tasks

Comment: This is SO.  What your teacher says isn't really germaine.  All the really matters is the code you post.

Comment: @Meteor2142 Does my answer solve the problem? If it does it would be nice of you to mark it as "Solution"